# My while or loop in a dice roll is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code

```
import random as r

Diceroll = "Y"
while Diceroll == "Y":
    Roll = r.randrange(1,7)
    print(Roll)
    Diceroll  = input("Would you like to roll again: Y/N")
    while (Diceroll != "Y") or (Diceroll != "N"):
        Diceroll = input("Please enter either Y or N")

print("Thank you for rolling with us")
```

After the first print it infinitely loops on `Would you like to roll again` 
I am sure the solution is obvious but I cannot find it.

Comment: `(Diceroll != "Y") or (Diceroll != "N")` is always true... `Diceroll not in ('Y', 'N')` might be better...

Comment: If `Diceroll` is "Y" then (Diceroll != "N") is True, and if `Diceroll` is "N" then (Diceroll != "Y") is True. And if `Diceroll` is neither "Y" or "N" both of those conditions will be True. So when will the combined condition `(Diceroll != "Y") or (Diceroll != "N")` ever be False? Now consider what happens with  `(Diceroll != "Y") and (Diceroll != "N")`, and take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 0):

You need a more constrained condition for inputs that are neither `Y` or `N`:

```
while (Diceroll != "Y") and (Diceroll != "N"):
    ...
```

Or

```
while Diceroll not in ('Y', 'N'):
    ...
```

Comment: or `while Diceroll not in "YN":` :)

Comment: @antonagestam Maybe. If the user inputs `"YN"` that'll be accepted by the inner `while`, but I guess that's ok because it'll be rejected by the outer `while`.

Comment: Oh, right. `while Diceroll[0] not in "YN":` would probably work though. But I'd prefer the first one with `while ... and ...:` anyway.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for clearing that up. It also avoids passing the empty string `''`

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be:

```
import random as r

Diceroll = "Y"
while Diceroll == "Y" and Diceroll != "N":
    Roll = r.randrange(1,7)
    print(Roll)
    Diceroll  = input("Would you like to roll again: Y/N")


print("Thank you for rolling with us")
```

below is the output:

```
4
Would you like to roll again: Y/NY
3
Would you like to roll again: Y/NY
6
Would you like to roll again: Y/NY
4
Would you like to roll again: Y/NY
1
Would you like to roll again: Y/NY
6
Would you like to roll again: Y/NY
6
Would you like to roll again: Y/NY
6
Would you like to roll again: Y/NN
Thank you for rolling with us
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a flaw in your program logic, by using the incorrect `logical operator`:

- Logical `AND` operator: returns True if both operands are True, and False if at least one is False
- Logical `OR` operator: returns True if one or both operands are True, and False if both are False

This is why `while (Diceroll != "Y") or (Diceroll != "N")` was returning `True` with input of `Y` or `N`